# Как обеспечить работоспособность JavaScript-обработчиков при использовании PJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2, pjax

Есть страница `view`, код которой обернут в `Pjax`, работающая под `Yii2`. На страницу подключён скрипт `js`. Обнаружил интересную особенность js-кода: он корректно работает, но если вернуться на страницу, с которой уходил (или кликом или возвратом на предыдущую страницу), js-код перестаёт работать.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
   // some code
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>

<?php
 $js = '$(function(){alert(123);})';
 $this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_END);
?>
```

Поведение предсказуемое - заново строится DOM, но я не смог найти способа решить проблему повторной установки js-обработчиков, либо установки таким образом, чтобы их работоспособность сохранилась.

Прошу совета, можно ли решить эту проблему.

Comment: В теге скрипт написать, нет?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду так: <script>alert("123") </script> ? Тот же результат - возврат на страницу, обрабатываемую PJAX, не обеспечивает срабатывание установленных на ней скриптов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением является установка обработчиков на неизменяемые в процессе перестроения DOM элементы, так называемая делегированная обработка событий:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clicked-element', function() {/* ... */});
```

В случае формы решение может выглядеть так:

```
$(document).on('submit', function(e) {/* ... */});
```

Подробности о делегированной обработке можно прочитать в [документации](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29).

Answer (score 0):

По идее можно на странице использовать:

```
$this->registerJs("
    $(document).on('ready pjax:end', function(event) {
        $(window).trigger('load');
    });
");
```